# Can this type theory interpret second order arithmetic?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, foundations, type-theory, theories-of-arithmetic

Language: multi-sorted first order logic with equality and membership, where for each natural $t$ there is a set $x^t$ of sort $t$. Equality "$=$" only occurs between variables of the same sort, and set membership "$\in$" can only be written with the variable on the right having one sort higher than the variable on the left.

**Axioms:**

**Extensionality:** $t=1,2,3,...; \\\forall z^{t-1} (z^{t-1} \in x^t \iff z^{t-1} \in y^t) \implies x^t=y^t$

**Comprehension:** $t=1,2,3,..; n=1,2,3,..; k_{i \in \{1,..,n\}}=0,2,3,..,t;  \\\forall w_1^{k_1},..,\forall w_n^{k_n}: (\exists y^{t-1}:\varphi^t) \implies \\\exists x^t \forall y^{t-1} (y^{t-1} \in x^t \iff \varphi^t) $

**Infinity:** $\{x^0 \mid x^0=x^0\} \text { is infinite}$

**Choice:** $t=0,1,2,3,...; \\\{x^t \mid x^t=x^t\} \text { is well-orderable }$

Where $\varphi^t$ is a typed-formula where $t$ is the maximal type of a variable in it; and in which "$x^t$" is not free. Infinite is after Dedekind's.

This is a kind of mildely impredicative type theory, it would be fully predicative if we further restrict $\varphi^t$ to only allow free occurrences in it to have type $t$. Which would mostly be weaker than $\sf PA$. However, this theory allows quantified variables in the defining formula of comprehension to  be of the same sort of the constructed set, and so it is impredicative, but it shuns higher types, so it imposes a kind of restriction on its impredicativity.

The restriction on comprehension imposed here is similar to that of [$\underline {\sf NFI}$](http://logoi.be/crabbe/textes/connfi.pdf) which is known to be equi-consistent with ${\sf Z}_2$. Hence the question:

> Can this theory interpet second order arithmetic ${\sf Z}_2$? Or at least interpret $\sf PA$?

Comment: If comprehension is allowed to quantify over the level of the set being generated, can't you just form the smallest inductive set of Frege cardinals? Wouldn't that give you second-order arithmetic pretty easily?

Comment: @JamesHanson, but induction is not full, it only works for the mildely impredicative formulas, so is that enough to reach second order arithmetic? However, you are right regarding the naturals, I can do that using the ordinary unordered pairing to define the bijections and then define the finite Frege cardinals, and it is easy to define addition and multiplication using Kuratowski pairs at two levels above the naturals. A kind of induction follows, I believe, from well ordering of the naturals. But not for all formulas.

Comment: You don't need induction for all formulas in your formalism to get second-order arithmetic. You just need induction for sets of naturals. Since you can define sets of naturals using formulas that quantify over sets of naturals, why don't you get induction for these formulas too?

Comment: @JamesHanson because some of those set theoretic based arithmetical formulas may not be equivalent to mildly impredicative formulas